# Google Cardboard Unity SDK - detecting back button press

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm working on a Google Cardboard app in unity and would like to exit VR mode when the phones back button is pressed.

I've tried detecting presses with Input.GetKey and Input.GetKeyDown with KeyCode.Escape. however this seems to always result in the application quitting no matter what. Is the back button's functionality written directly into the .jar used for the cardboard SDK?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The back button is currently hard coded in the .jar to exit the app, in keeping with standard Android practice where the back button pops the Activity stack.  It may be possible to make that an option in the SDK.

Update for v0.4.5 of the SDK:  There's an option to control whether the Back button exits the app, or appears as an Escape key press.